# If $G$ has both chain conditions, then there is no proper $H \leq G$ with $G \cong H$, and no normal nontrivial $K \leq G$ with $G/K \cong G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been self-studying group theory, and thinking for a while without much progress on this exercise (Rotman “An Introduction to the Theory of Groups”, Exercise 6.31):

**If $G$ has both chain conditions (that is, every ascending or descending chain of normal subgroups of $G$ is eventually constant), then there is no proper $H \leq G$ with $G \cong H$, and no normal nontrivial $K \leq G$ with $G/K \cong G$.**

My thoughts so far: if $H$ were characteristic in $G$ then we could easily construct an infinite descending chain of normal subgroups of $G$ by repeatedly applying the isomorphism $G \to H$, contradicting DCC. Trying to aim for a contradiction with the Krull-Schmidt theorem (since this exercise is after a section leading up to the Krull-Schmidt theorem), I get that $H$ and $G$ contain the same number of indecomposable factors, so if we could write $G$ as a direct product including those factors of $H$ (and others), then that would be a contradiction, but that would only be possible in the case that $H$ is itself a direct factor of G. I have also tried constructing various endomorphisms on the indecomposable factors of $G$ and $H$ (by composing with projections), to use the lemma that those endomorphisms must either be surjective or nilpotent.

Comment: $H$ would contain a proper subgroup isomorphic to $H$ would contain a proper subgroup isomorphic to $H$ would contain a proper subgroup isomorphic to $H$ would contain... etc. $G/K$ would have a nontrivial subgroup such that the quotient is isomorphic to $G$ would have a nontrivial subgroup such that the quotient is isomorphic to $G$ would have a nontrivial subgroup such that the quotient is isomorphic to $G$...etc.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, that exhibits an infinite descending chain, but are all of those subgroups normal in $G$? In fact $H$ is not even given to be normal in $G$. If $H$ is characteristic in $G$ then these subgroups are all normal in $G$, but otherwise I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the statement is actually false as given (maybe Rotman meant for $H$ to be characteristic in $G$, or to be a direct factor of $G$?) A counterexample is given by the infinite simple group $A_\infty$, since by simplicity it trivially satisfies both chain conditions, but it has a proper subgroup isomorphic to itself, namely the subgroup of permutations fixing $1$.

As for the second part, if $f : G/K \to G$ is an isomorphism and $v : G \to G/K$ is the quotient map, then $\phi = f \circ v : G \to G$ is a surjective (but not injective) homomorphism. Now consider:

$$1 < \text{ker }\phi < \text{ker }\phi^2 < \text{ker }\phi^3 < \ldots$$